# for-comprehension returns None if at least one component in `for` is None

Tags: scala, flatmap, for-comprehension

I have difficulty understanding the mechanism using for-compression in Scala. 
For example, if I have

```
val x = for {
  i <- Option(1)
  j <- Option(2)
  k <- Option(3)
} yield (i,j,k)
```

`x` is `x: Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = Some((1,2,3))`.
However, if at least one of component is None, for example,

```
val x = for {
  i <- Option(1)
  j <- Option(2)
  k <- None
} yield (i,j,k)
```

then `x` is `x: Option[(Int, Int, Nothing)] = None`, while I actually hoped to see something like : `x: Option[(Int, Int, Nothing)] = Some((1,2,None))`.

I have checked the [FAQ from Scala official documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) where it is specifically stated that `for-comprehension` is a combination of `flatmap` and `map`. But I still have difficulty understanding that `x` is `None`.

I think I missed some important concepts on `flatmap` and `map` difference.

Comment: `for { a <- A; b <- B } yield b` is the same as `A.flatMap { a => B.map { b => b } }`. Also, `None.flatMap(f) === None` & `None.map(f) === None`. Thus, as you said, if at least one element is a **None**, then the result of the for will be **None** _(that is why it is said that None  acts like a short circuit, because it will ignore everything after it)_. - Additionally, `Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = Some((None,2,3))` is wrong, since you said the first element of the tuple will be an `Int` and you passed it a **None** _(which has type `Option[Nothing]`)_ so it will not type check. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first for-comprehension "desugars" into:

```
val x = Option(1).flatMap(
  i => Option(2).flatMap(
    j => Option(3).map(
      k => (i, j, k)
    )
  )
)
```

As you can see - the first Option is flat-mapped using a function that takes its value (if it exists) and returns a 3-tuple (using similar operation on the 2nd Option). Regardless of what that function is - the entire expression is of the form:

```
val x = Option(1).flatMap(f)
```

Now, if we replace `Option(1)` with `None` (as you did in second expression) we'd clearly get `None`:

```
val x = None.flatMap(f) // None, for any f
```

The result that you expected (`Some((None, 2, 3))`) is not too useful - as it would have *different types* for different inputs: Would it be `(Option[Int], Int, Int)`? Or `(Int, Int, Int)`? Or `(Option[Int], Option[Int], Option[Int])`? Really the only common type for `(None, 2, 3)`, `(1, None, 3)` and `(1, 2, None)` is the not-so-useful `(Any, Any, Any)`.

Comment: Interesting point re: the type usefulness, but I would tend to see it more a consideration of consistency across collections (with `Option` being treated as a collection).  Consider the case of a `for-comprehension` on `List` like `for { i <- List(); j <- List(1); k <- List(2) } yield (i, j, k)`, which could be viewed as collecting tuples of (i, j, k) while traversing a 3-dimensional array in the conventional `for-loop`.  If one of the dimensions is of size `0`, the size of the resultant `List` should be `0` (in this case `0 x 1 x 1`).